# How to use mouse to move window in XZ plane in opengl

Tags: opengl

I want to move the view in the XZ plane, when I move the mouse. The `mlon` and `mlat` which are linear function of mouse coordinate x and y. I have `glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouse_motion);` in my main function. What I need to do in order to move the window view in the XZ plane? Any explanation?

```
void mouse_motion(int x, int y) {

 /* To be completed */
 x=lon+mlon;
 y=lat+mlat;

} // mouse_motion()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with calling glutPostRedisplay in the mouse motion handler so that the scene gets redrawn. Redraw with the updated position.